# Problem in copying data of one NSDictionary to another

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

Hello i am having problem in copying data from one NSDictionary to another i used the

```
[dicForFoodproduct_fromWeb initWithDictionary:dictforfoodproduct];
```

Here it terminates and says "unrecognized selecter sent to the instance..." I am getting 5 key values in `dictForFoodProduct` but am unable to copy that key values into `dicForFoodProduct_fromWeb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *newDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:otherDictionary];
```

Comment: mrugen: Don't ever send an `init` or `initWithWhatever:` message to an already-initialized instance. It always causes other problems—maybe obvious, maybe subtle, but always serious enough that you should never do this. You should only ever initialize an uninitialized instance—i.e., one just returned by `alloc` or `allocWithZone:`.

Comment: ya thansk  for your inputs ,will  take care of that

Comment: Yes sorry for the lack of additional context in my original answer. Peter's comments are words to live/code by. If you have a mutable dictionary there are other methods to replace contents with another dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

`[dicForFoodproduct_fromWeb addEntriesFromDictionary: dictforfoodproduct]`

This will replace existing values with the dictforfoodproduct values.  Only difference from using an init is that it won't remove values that aren't present in dictforfoodproduct but that are in dicForFoodproduct_fromWeb.